# noSuchMethod for class Methods (a.k.a. static methods)

Tags: reflection, static, dart

I've been using dart for quite a while now. If I want to implement dynamic getters, setters and functions for objects of a class, I can make use of the noSuchMethod-method. But what if I now want to have such a dynamic getter, setter of method on class layer? In Ruby, for example, if one wants to implement a dynamic class method, one would define the `method_missing`-method on the class object, like for example:

```ruby
class Test
    def self.method_missing
        //Do some matching, return result or error
    end
end
```

How would I achieve this in Dart?

Comment: Do you have a use case for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in Dart without mirrors/reflection.

I also don't think this is very useful.
You can't call a static method on a 'dynamic' type and therefore you can't mock static methods.

If you need this you should just make it a normal method instead of a static one.

Comment: Yes, but what if for example I wanted to implement something like ActiveRecords find-Functions (like Model.find_one_by_username)? Wouldn't this need a static method?

Comment: I don't know active record but why needs `find_one_by_username` to be static. You can make a library variable `Model` and assign `new Model()` to it then you can call it's instance method `Model.find_one_by_username()`. (I don't suggest naming a library variable uppercase - I used this casing just for the sake of your example to make it look equal)

Comment: You can create a `MyObjectRepository` aside of  `MyObject` and use `noSuchMethod` on this repository object. It's almost the same thing as static methods. You can also add this Repository as static member of MyObject. Thus `MyObject.REPO.find_one_by_username(...)` will be close to activeRecord API.

Answer (score 1):

You can just override `noSuchMethod` as noticed [here](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/emulating-functions/#interactions-with-mirrors-and-nosuchmethod)